# Create user with curtin installer - MAAS

Tags: maas, curtin

I'm trying to create a user with a non-encrypted password in my server deployed via MAAS using curtin installer.

User: `installer`
Password: `lowpass`

In my `curtin_userdata` file I have these lines:

```
late_commands:
  90_create_installer: ["sh", "-c", "sudo useradd installer -g 0"]
  92_set_installer_password: ["sh", "-c", "echo 'installer:lowpass' | sudo chpasswd"]
  94_cat: ["sh", "-c", "cat /etc/passwd"]
```

In MAAS log while the `cat /etc/passwd` is running this line appears well :

```
installer:x:1001:0::/home/installer:
```

But once it's finished, I connect to my server and then the user is not present anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I found out my problem: I wasn't using the `in-target` command!